# at.js npm package not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, npm

I am trying to use Webpack to include [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/at.js) to my project:

```
require('at.js');
```

But it looks like this package has error.

The error message is not giving helpful information.

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Question 1:**

Is it my mistake or the package is faulty? If you try to load it here, it says error.

https://tonicdev.com/npm/at.js

**Question 2:**

This package is suppose from [this github](https://github.com/ichord/At.js) repo. If the existing NPM package is faulty, how can I make one myself based on the github repo?

Comment: Seeing as the repo has quite a few known issues and pull requests, and that there are several questions regarding the package on SO, it has worked for others. What is the issue you're having, what does the error say etc. You have to be more specific than just "has error".

Comment: Q: Can yout fetch the package directly from npm (instead of using webpack)?  And please specify exactly what "looks like this package has error" means!

Comment: Updated question, thanks!

Comment: Those screenshots are very hard to read! You shold consider turning off the transparency on your terminal

Comment: @hugomg thanks for the complain, I normally only read red or green color.